# when I run my program on spark cluster,how can I choose quicker machine to run my program?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark cluster which contain 8 machines,
but two of them are old computers and run slowly,
so I want to make just 6 of them run,
I just know that i can use --num-executor to make 6 computers to run,
but i want to make 6 new computers running my program,how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Yarn as a resource manager, you could specify the executor's memory size to be larger than the amount available on the older computers. This would allow you to achieve what you're looking for. (--executor-memory 10g)

Otherwise, you'll need a feature called Yarn Labels:[YARN-796](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-796)